# .htaccess - Redirect "folder/file" to "file"

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

In my `.htaccess`

I want:

```
login/file.php?username=abc&password=123 -> login.php?username=abc&password=123
```

I want to forward all parameters from `login/file.php` to `login.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this into you .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?login/file\.php$ /login.php [QSA,L]
```

All Query Strings will be added as well

Answer (score 0):

After some tests I end up with this line in my .htaccess file, and it works fine.

```
RewriteRule ^login/file.php login.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.